# How Do I Prove this is a Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Question:

Prove that the set of real $n\times n$ matrices with n distinct eigenvalues is a manifold.

Attempt:

I wish to show that this set is an open subset of the set of all real $n\times n$ matrices, since $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is a manifold, and an open subset of a manifold is a manifold. However, I don’t know the map to use to make this possible (i.e. I don’t know what to map $Mat(n, \mathbb{R})$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is an open subset.

Comment: Consider the function that maps a matrix to its eigenvalues (ordered from smallest to largest, say). Is it continuous?

Comment: @Karl The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of its characteristic polynomial. And the characteristic polynomial’s coefficients are continuous functions of the entries of the matrix. What I don’t know is how to restrict this to eigenvalues with no multiplicities, and how to map a matrix to these eigenvalues.

Comment: One way to do this (not sure if there's a simpler method): exterior powers of trace give you all the symmetric polynomials of the eigenvalues, and so the discriminant is a polynomial in those values, and should be zero precisely when two eigenvalues are equal.

Comment: It seems to me that the roots of the characteristic polynomial vary continuously with the coefficients, so if $M$ is a matrix with distinct eigenvalues then there is an open neighborhood of $M$ in which the eigenvalues remain distinct. Am I making a mistake?